# Customizing JSON object property names with Spray JSON

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

I'm using spray-json to serialize an object tree, which is based on a class hierarchy such as this:

```
trait Base {
  val _id: Long
}

case class Person(_id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String) extends Base
case class Company(_id: Long, name: String) extends Base
```

This is of course a contrived example, the real codebase contains many classes and fields. The idea, however, is that there's a trait that contain some common values.
Now the question is if there's a way I can format the JSON such that instead of `_id` the property name would be just `id`.

Now before you jump and tell to extend `JsonFormat`, the question is whether I can implement this *just once* for all classes that extend `Base`, without implementing a format for each of the classes. As I mentioned, there are many classes, and implementing custom formats for each would be quite tedious and I assume will require quite a lot of maintenance. It would be nice if I could annotate the `_id` val in `Base` for example. Is there anything that can be done to avoid implementing formats for each of the classes?

Comment: You can use `jsonFormat(Person, "id", "firstName", "lastName")` to set the names of the fields (instead of `jsonFormat3(Person)`).

Comment: @jrudolph It's not ideal, because I still need to define it separately for each class. However, it's probably easiest way to go with spray-json. Could you please write it as an answer here so I could mark it as the best answer? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, another possibility that people have been using is overriding `ProductFormat.extractFieldNames` to provide a general mapping on the names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is jrudolph's comment as an answer, to make it easy for people to see.  Great solution!

> You can use `jsonFormat(Person, "id", "firstName", "lastName")` to set
>   the names of the fields (instead of `jsonFormat3(Person)`).

jrudolph, if you change your comment to an answer, I'll delete this.